# PostgreSQL how to check if parameter exists in a function

Tags: postgresql

In SQL Server, I can validate if a specific parameter exists in a given Stored Procedure like so:

```
SELECT [name]
FROM sys.parameters 
WHERE object_id = object_id('MyStoredProc')
AND [name]='@paramenter_im_checking'
```

Is there an equivalent in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Not that I know of. But it seems nonsensical to check for the existence of a parameter that you declared in the same function - this is static information that cannot change at run time.

Comment: I simplified the example, my real use case is that the stored procedure to check for parameter existence is not static.. it's coming from a setup table

Comment: Your parameter names don't come from a lookup table, they are fixed. So just repeat the parameter name in the function body.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - The actual query looks like... " WHERE object_id=object_id(@SomeStoredProc) ". The SomeStoredProc can be any stored procedure. That stored proc may or may not have the parameter I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the system catalog `pg_proc` for named parameters of a function or procedure:

```
SELECT 'parameter_name' =ANY (proargnames)
FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc
WHERE proname = 'function_name';
```

This will return `TRUE` or `FALSE`, depending on whether the function or procedure has a parameter of that name or not.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I also need to check the schema in case the same function name exists in more than one Schemas.

Here's the updated query:

```
SELECT 'parameter_name' = ANY (proargnames)
FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc p INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n 
ON n.oid = p.pronamespace
WHERE n.nspname='schema_name'
AND proname = 'function_name';
```